# Running 'code .' in MacOS terminal no longer opens VSCode. Python error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, visual-studio-code, zsh

Previously, I've been able to open a directory in VS Code by running `code .` in the terminal. I'm not sure when it stopped working but recently it has. I'm running on MacOS 12.3 beta 2.

I have Python 3.9.10 installed via Homebrew. Brew says all the symlinks are linked but I'm not so sure. Just running regular `python -V` no longer is valid, I can only run via `python3 -V`

[image]

I have run the command from inside VS Code `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` multiple times to no avail.

Comment: One route would be to edit /usr/local/bin/code and replace `python` with `python3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In macOS 12.3 beta Apple removed support for Python 2. Additionally
> Python 3 no longer comes bundled with macOS. This causes the code
> command to not work anymore.

[makaracc](https://github.com/makaracc) has provided a solution:

cd /usr/local/bin

nano code

change python => python3 on the following line

```
- function realpath() { python -c ...
+ function realpath() { python3 -c ...
```

And you can wait for the update.

You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141738) for more details.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

My symlink looks like this:
`code -> /Users/myUserName/OtherApplications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code`

Double check the path to code, `which code` will do it.
If that fails, then it's not in your path.

If your symlink, and your path to it are both correct you should be ready to go.  If you need to make a new symlink `ln -s [file_you_want_to_link_to] [the_name_of_your_new_link]`

If you need to find the executable: From your home directory (just  `cd` and hit enter will take you there) and if, like me, your VS Code is installed under your home directory, `find ~ -type f -name code` will find it.

If it's installed system-wide, then `find /Applications/ -type f -name code` will find it there.

Once you find the executable, use the above `ln -s` command to make a symlink, but do it from somewhere in your path.

I simplify my life by creating my own bin directory for all my little scripts right in my home directory.  I call mine "mybin" and used `mkdir ~/mybin` to create it. In my .bash_profile (in my home directory) I have a line like this: `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/myUserName/homebrew/bin:/Users/myUserName/mybin"`

Which is where my symlink to code lives. :)

Once you locate code and make a symlink to it somewhere in your path, `code .` should work again.

To make my symlink, I did this from inside
~/mybin `ln -s "/Users/myUserName/OtherApplications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" code` (I needed to put the path to code in quotes because it has spaces in it).

Comment: I misunderstood.  You can do ```which python``` and ```which python3``` if you have to, make them both point to the same file, mine look like this: ```lrwxr-xr-x  1 root         wheel  75 Dec  7 15:39 /usr/bin/python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7``` and 
```lrwxr-xr-x  1 myUserName  admin  38 Jan  4 17:41 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/bin/python3```